# Online storage for iPhone , android apps and alternates to custom webservices

Tags: php, iphone, asp.net, android, mysql

For my previous iPhone or android apps to store data online, I use either asp .net & ms-sql or php-mysql server. I create stored procedures then web-services in php/asp .net and interact to those services by my mobile app.

That all works fine.

But for manipulating even a single table I have to do a lot of work. 
Is there some pre-made framework by which I only create table and store and data retrieval from table is automatic and I don't have to create web-services.

I hope there must be some pre-made framework for this, is there? 
And if its there then how can I use that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try using amazon simple db, its a paid SaaS, Its not only the framework, its a database platform (NoSQL) with api to use that.